# Find all combinations of a number sequence which is first increasing then decreasing

Tags: performance, algorithm, c, combinatorics

> Given an integer N(Natural Number), A program/Algorithm to find the
>   remainder of arrangements that can be obtained by rearranging the
>   numbers **1, 2, ...., N**.
>
> Input Format: One line containing the integer **N**
>
> Output Format: An integer m, giving the remainder of the number of
>   arrangements that could be obtained from **1, 2, ...., N** is divide
>   by Mod
>
> Constraints:
>   **Mod = 10^9+7**
>   **N ≤ 10^9**
>
> Example 1
>  
> Input
>   **3**  
> Output
>   **2**  
> Explanation:
>  Consider the **first three natural numbers 1, 2, 3**. These can be arranged in the following ways: 2, 3, 1 and 1,
>   3, 2. In both of these arrangements, the numbers increase to a certain
>   point and then decrease. There are two such arrangements: 2, 3, 1 and
>   1, 3, 2.
>
> Example 2
>
> Input
>   **4**  
> Output
>   **6**  
> Explanation:
>  The six arrangements are (**1, 2, 4, 3), (1,3,4,2), (1,4,3,2), (2,3,4,1), (2,4,3,1), (3,4,2,1)**.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define m 1000000007

unsigned long long int power(unsigned long long int x, unsigned long long int n){

    unsigned long long int res = 1;
    while(n > 0){
        if(n & 1){
            res = res * x;
            res = res%m;
        }
        x = x * x;
        x= x%m;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return res;

}


int main(){

    unsigned long long int n,res=0,temp=1,i;
    scanf("%llu", &n);
    if(n==1 || n==0){
        printf("0\n");
        return 0;
    }
    temp = power(2, n-1);
    temp--;
    temp--;
    printf("%llu\n", temp);

    return 0;
}
```

Can Anyone Solve This with Better Time Complexity?

Comment: An explanation of the combinatorics behind the scenes would be most helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Bug

```
Input : 500000003
Output: 18446744073709551615
```

The problem is that the result of your `power()` call could be 0 or 1.  Then when you subtract 2, you get a negative number.  Given the input constaint of \$n ≤ 10^9\$, 500000003 is the only bad input, but in general this happens when `n` is any multiple of 500000003.  To correct this, you could change this:

> ```
> temp--;
> temp--;
> ```

to:

```
temp = (temp + m - 2) % m;
```

This ensures that `temp` will remain positive.  Time complexity wise, your program is great at \$O(\log n)\$.

Comment: It has to deal with only natural number then why to count 0 ?

Comment: Why the answer is \$2^{n-1} - 2\$ is quite clear. I wanted OP to confirm that he knows that. You shouldn't interfere. I know that you know. Sorry.

Comment: @HimanshuRay Apparently you didn't really understand the problem so I removed my explanation.

Comment: @vnp I think you were right, judging from the above comment by OP.

Comment: my mistake @JS1 sorry. You can put back your Explanation. I will go through it once more.